# Android file uploading using loopj HttpClient

Tags: java, android, file, android-async-http

I'm uploading files(Images,Videos and Audios) from Android side to PHP server. It's working good for small files. But for large files it is giving unexpected results, like file uploads but on android side it gives timeout exception.
So please help me, how i tackle all the scenarios for file uploading. How i can use HttpMultipart entity and how i can set relative timeout against different size files.
My code is:

```
File myFile = new File(filePath);
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
try {
    params.put("uploaded_file", myFile);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
}

URL=getResources().getString(com.newing.R.string.server_adderess)+URL+fileType+"&lessonID="+LessonID;
client.post(URL, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String response) {
        Log.w("async", "success!!!!");
        UtilityFunctions.showNotification(getApplicationContext(),
            "File uploading completed.");
        stopSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable error) {
        Log.w("async", "failure!!!!");
        UtilityFunctions.showNotification(getApplicationContext(),
            "File couldn't upload. Please try later.");
        stopSelf();
    } 
});
```

Comment: Can you check the max_size limit for upload on your server? And the timeout value?

Answer (score 0):

you can try use Ion is a great library for Asynchronous Networking and Image Loading https://github.com/koush/ion

a simple example uploading a file

`Ion.with(getContext(), "https://koush.clockworkmod.com/test/echo")
.uploadProgressBar(uploadProgressBar)
.setMultipartFile("filename.zip", new File("/sdcard/filename.zip"))
.asJsonObject()
.setCallback(...)`

check the project site for more examples and wiki

Comment: Question how to resolve using loopj. Don't suggest new plugin.